# Can not import the package which i installed via Pycharm(pandas-datareader

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

Can not import pandas_datareader package. Python told me that No module named 'pandas_datareader'

installed the pandas_datareader via pycharm.

```
import pandas.datareader as web
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-0106485ab891>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas.datareader as web

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.datareader'
```

```
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

```
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python35.zip
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.3.5-py3.5.egg
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\ilike\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\ilike\.ipython
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you let me know the output when you go to the Python shell, and try `import pandas.datareader as web` ? It can help us isolate and check if the module was installed correctly in the first place. Also, try a `import pandas_datareader` command on the CLI.

Comment: i already try 'import pandas_datareader as web'. I guess something wrong with path but not sure

Comment: You need to try redoing or retracing your steps. Maybe do your Python Environment Variable setup for Windows again?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Hi, please modify your question saying you tried the official correct import way (pandas_datareader).  
On my Linux install, the installation via Pycharm works fine, and the package is installed under the following path : `/.../anaconda3/pkgs/pandas-datareader-0.7.0-py36_0` . Did you check where is yours ?  
By the way, maybe check the Project Interpreter for which you installed the package, often anaconda users have several interpreters proposed (Settings- > Project:*** -> Project Interpreter)

Answer (score 2):

What about `import pandas_datareader as web` ?

Comment: Indeed it is @Edel, sarotto check the [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage)